# Eclipse Schlumberger 100 in oil engineering

Tags: simulation, simulator

My question is about [Eclipse Schlumberger](https://www.software.slb.com/products/eclipse) software, which has nothing to do with the Java IDE.
Do you have any examples for the simulation of a radial reservoir by *Eclipse Schlumberger*?

Comment: [ECLIPSE Schlumberger](https://www.software.slb.com/products/eclipse) has nothing to do with the open source IDE [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) and I'm wondering why Schlumberger uses [the trademark](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/logo_guidelines.php).

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, this question needs a new tag (and not `eclipse`). I didn't find a suiting one, so I pass that task on to the community.